# flex: move item around in a tree control

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tree, insertion

I have a tree control and I want to give the user the ability that he can move up and down the element he just selected with a up and a downbutton. The tree gets generated from XML.

I managed to insert the selected item a second time at a other place, with the following code:

```
var parentXML:XML = XML(containerTree.selectedItem).parent();

var upperItem:XML = topContainer.source[containerTree.selectedIndex-1]; 

parentXML.insertChildBefore(upperItem,XML(containerTree.selectedItem));
```

but then I have the item there twice in the List. How can I remove to reinsert it?

Thanks for Hints!
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the `delete (XML)` operator to [remove XML nodes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#appendChild()).

```
var parentXML:XML = XML(containerTree.selectedItem).parent();

var upperItem:XML = topContainer.source[containerTree.selectedIndex-1]; 

delete containerTree.selectedItem;

parentXML.insertChildBefore(upperItem,XML(containerTree.selectedItem));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, assuming containerTree is a "Tree" Component: 
1189: Attempt to delete the fixed property selectedItem.  Only dynamically defined properties can be deleted.